# libpng14-14.dll was not found

Tags: c++, windows, dll, system32

i've searched about `This application failed to start because libpng14-14.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem.` and i found that my problem can be caused by this : `Uninstalling or installing applications can also make your registry of Windows full with corrupted, harmful and obsolete files` (Note:  i've reinstalled all visual studio from 2005 to 2015 on `c:\` . (as required from my superior at work for a new c++ project))

Because politics&stuff i cannot install whatever i want, so, my question is: is there a way to solve this easly?

I've tried step 1 from this [How To Fix Libpng14-14.dll is Missing / Not Found Error Messages](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/files/missing-not-found-error/dll/windows/windows-software-developer/third-party-software/libpng14-14-dll/) and apparently i have no such file on my machine. :(

Feel free to edit this post/tags.

Comment: try putting the dll where the executable you are trying to run is located. You would still need the dll though.

Comment: I'v tried, but the dll is on x86 and my project is build under x64. I receive 0x00007b error. I guess that i need libpng14-14.dll on x64 :-? and as far as i know is not recommended to download ddls.

Comment: is the program being compiled for 64 bit? if yes you need the 64 bit dll otherwise you can change it to 32 under visual studio.

Comment: yes, it's compiled for x64 :(

Comment: Go to your project's property pages, find the Linker -> Advanced -> Target Machine option, and make sure it is set to MachineX86.

Comment: If *apparently i have no such file on my machine* is true, then it's clear what the solution will be. Find the file (or the package/library/application that includes it) and get it on your machine. Clearly it can't load the DLL if the DLL doesn't exist on your machine, and just as clearly there's no magic wand we can wave from here that will make it suddenly appear. :-)

Comment: In the solutions platform drop down make sure you select "Win32" for the x86 change.

Comment: Solved, I borrowed the dll from a coleg :D, now i have other dependencies missing :)) Thanks.

Comment: No problem I added summary of the above in the ans.

Answer (score 1):

For completion,

Add the dll where the executable you are trying to run is located. If the program being compiled for 64 bit you need a 64 bit dll in this case 64 bit version of the libpng14-14.dll